# add separator listview jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, css, listview, jquery-mobile

i have jquery mobile list view.
can anybody help me please, to customize this listview.
i want to customize the separator between list, so its will look like this 
[image: space separator]

here is my code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/_assets/css/jqm-docs.css"/>
 <div data-role="page" id="mainn">

 <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>

            </div>

            <div data-role="content">           
           <ul id="promoList" data-role="listview" >
             <li>
            <img src="airasia.jpg" >
            <span class="ui-li-count">test 123</span>
            </li>


            <li>
            <img src="d1380513326.jpg">
            <span class="ui-li-count">test 124</span>
            </li>

            </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using a JQM version of March 2013, how could you expect someone will help you in June 2017?

Comment: i knew it, the problem is not because JQM, i will update the latest one. but what i need is a css to make a style to make separator between <ul style=xxxxxxx> or <li style=yyyyyy>